# How would you convert this code to best take advantage of CSS transform for panning/zooming?

Tags: javascript, css, functional-programming, matrix, react.js

I am using `react-flow-chart` for a job project, but it doesn't implement zoom, and I would like to take the reigns and try applying it myself. I took a linear algebra class in college, but I am not very good at transformations. I could make my job a lot easier if I directly use CSS transforms and have it do the heavy lifting for me.

## Code

I have put the in a CodeSandbox repo and have organized it as best as I could for clarity, so I recommend viewing the complete code from there, and fork it for significant changes.

## https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wood-ksfbs?fontsize=14

### App.js

```js
export const App = () => {
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState([[0, 0], [20, 20], [50, 20]]);
  const [canvasPosition, setCanvasPosition] = useState([0, 0]);

  const onPositionChanged = R.curry((index, pos) => {
    if (index === "canvas") return setCanvasPosition(pos);
    setSquares(R.update(index, pos));
  });

  return (
    <Canvas
      position={canvasPosition}
      onPositionChanged={onPositionChanged}
      squares={squares}
    />
  );
};
```

### Canvas.js

This is the part where I calculate each square's position and render it

```js
const calculateSquarePosition = R.pipe(
    mult(scale),
    add(canvas),
    add(drag)
  );

  const onSquarePositionChanged = index =>
    R.pipe(
      add(neg(drag)),
      add(neg(canvas)),
      mult(1 / scale),
      onPositionChanged(index)
    );

  const renderSquare = (pos, index) => (
    <Square
      key={index}
      scale={scale}
      position={calculateSquarePosition(pos)}
      onPositionChanged={onSquarePositionChanged(index)}
    />
  );
```

The part where I handle zooming by mouse wheel:

```js
  const onWheel = event => {
    const wheelDelta = event.deltaY;
    const newScale = R.pipe(
      R.add(wheelDelta * 0.001),
      clamp(0.2, 8)
    )(scale);

    const screenPos = getClientPos(event);
    const canvasToMouse = add(canvas, neg(screenPos));
    const normalizedCanvasToMouse = normalize(canvasToMouse);

    const distance = length(canvasToMouse);
    const newDistance = (distance / scale) * newScale;
    const newCanvasToMouse = mult(newDistance, normalizedCanvasToMouse);
    const newCanvas = add(screenPos, newCanvasToMouse);
    onPositionChanged("canvas", newCanvas);
    setScale(newScale);
  };
```

## Explanation

My app consists of a `Canvas,` which has a specified width and height. I made a `useDrag` hook that allows it to listen for drag events and gives the `drag displacement` which can be used to translate the `canvas position`, which mostly moves all the `Square`s together (as the `Canvas` can be considered the parent element). `Square`s are also draggable.

Things get more complicated when the scale is involved as I have to translate view coords to scaled view coords etc. correctly.

I want to know what changes I should make to make the transformations, state management, and just the math work for me in the most natural way. I feel like there should a better way, but I am not sure how.

The ultimate goal is to transfer what I know into the `react-flow-chart` and implement the zoom myself, and hopefully give a pull request (my first ever.)

Please let me know of *anything* that could be improved in this code. I welcome any criticism/feedback.